# JPG as a Window Icon using XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to use a JPG file as a Window Icon using strictly XAML?  I've found examples where you can use a BitmapFrame within C# to generate an ImageSource on the fly (which is then assignable to the Icon property), but I'd love to do something like:

<Window.Icon>
    <SomeXAMLThatLetsMeUseJpg Source="MyJpg.jpg" />
</Window.Icon>

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jpg as an icon directly.

Add your icon to the project as a resource, then use it as an icon:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
     <!--some more properties are set here...-->
     Icon="myicon.jpg">
</Window>
```

The jpg is automatically resized.